# Is there an easier way to define multiple condition Prop Types than by making own validator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

What if i would want prop to be type of number and in the same time required? As far as i know i have to make own validator for that. Is there any easier, elegant way?

```
function ShopxItem(props) {
    return (
        <>
            {props.name}
            {props.price}
        </>
    )
}

function PropTypesExample(){
    return (
        <>
            <ShopxItem name="1" price="xdd"></ShopxItem>
        </>
    )
}


ShopxItem.propTypes = {
//i would want to do it in that way but this overwrite "price" and returning an error "Duplicate Key xxx"
    price: PropTypes.number,
    price: PropTypes.isRequired,

// but as far as i know i have to do this like that
    price: (props, propName, componentName) => {
        let error;
        const prop = props[propName];
        if(prop === undefined || isNaN(prop)){error = new Error(`${componentName} price is required and have to be a number`);return error;}
        return null;
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like this should work:**

```js
price: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.func]).isRequired
```

We switched to using [air-bnb's `or`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airbnb-prop-types) for this purpose, instead of `oneOfType`, although I can't remember why exactly. In any case that package may also be of interest to you.

Comment: That works thank you but i have one more question if you know the answer. Do i can make custom errors message for that way like in validators? Because now i receiving "Failed prop type: Invalid prop `price` supplied to `ShopxItem`" and i think that isn't to clear that prop is required and have to be a number.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible without all the work involved in custom validators. I think our errors are probably vague like that unfortunately - but maybe they're not? Maybe that was the reason we chose to use Air-Bnb's `or` function instead? Sorry I can't give you a more concrete answer there.